# No such file or directory when exporting files using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu-16.04, mdbtools

I am working on a bash script which iterates over `mdb` files and exports them to a `csv`.

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

YEAR="2001/"
INFOLDER="/local/data/datasets/Convergence/"
OUTFOLDER="~/Workspaces/Ventilator_Repository/dataset/csv/"
for f in "$INFOLDER$YEAR*.mdb";
do
    absname=$INFOLDER$YEAR$(basename $f)
    echo "input file: $absname"
    streamingFile="$OUTFOLDER$YEAR$(basename $f)_streaming.csv"
    echo "output file: $streamingFile"
    streamcommand="mdb-export -d , $absname STREAMING > ${streamingFile}"
    echo "command: $streamcommand"
    mdb-export "-d , " $absname " STREAMING" > $streamingFile
done
```

However, I am getting this error:

> input file: /local/data/datasets/Convergence/2001/14a_25Sep2001_102404.mdb
>
> output file: ~/Workspaces/Ventilator_Repository/dataset/csv/2001/14a_25Sep2001_102404.mdb_streaming.csv
>
> command: **mdb-export -d , /local/data/datasets/Convergence/2001/14a_25Sep2001_102404.mdb STREAMING > ~/Workspaces/Ventilator_Repository/dataset/csv/2001/14a_25Sep2001_102404.mdb_streaming.csv**

However, I get the following error:

> line 14: ~/Workspaces/Ventilator_Repository/dataset/csv/2001/14a_25Sep2001_102404.mdb_streaming.csv: No such file or directory

If I run the *command* in the terminal, the export works fine! I do not know why in the bash script it does not work.

I am using mdb-tools to export `mdb` MS Access files into `csv` and my machine runs on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: `~` loses its special meaning inside quotes.

Comment: And are you certain `-d ,` is supposed to be in quotes? That's very unusual. Generally a program expects the `,` to be either passed as the immediately next character from `-d`, or as a subsequent argument list entry.

Comment: Similarly, leaving your variable expansions *unquoted* is almost certainly wrong. Consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and fixing what it finds.

Comment: A correct invocation is more likely to look like: `mdb-export -d , "$absname" STREAMING >"$streamingFile"`

Comment: ...and btw, all-caps variable names are used by variables with meaning to the OS or system, whereas names with lowercase characters are guaranteed safe for application use (or, rather, guaranteed not to conflict with names meaningful to POSIX-specified tools). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable (thus making the namespace shared).

Comment: Good point! Removed double quotes. Thanks!